# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

When I try to install the `google_calendar` in 7.0, got this below **error**:

```
File "/home/jack/workspace/7.0/7.0-calendar/google_calendar/controllers/main.py", line 11, in <module>
class google_calendar_controller(http.Controller):
File "/home/jack/workspace/7.0/7.0-calendar/google_calendar/controllers/main.py", line 13, in google_calendar_controller
@http.route('/google_calendar/sync_data', type='json', auth='user') 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'route'
```

can any one help??